# G5 iMac not recognizing lubuntu bootable flash drive

Tags: macos, bootable-media, lubuntu

I am trying to replace the operating system on an old G5 iMac with lubuntu.

I downloaded the lubuntu ISO file and converted it to an img with hdiutil, then used the dd command to move the img onto a flash drive.

I then restarted and held down the option key to get Into the startup manager (or whatever it is called) and the only bootable devise it detected was the main hard drive.

How can I get this to work, or using any other method, put lubuntu on my old iMac (from 2007 ish)

Comment: I think that's a powerpc (not intel compatible) cpu, do you use a powerpc linux image?

Comment: G5 Macs are indeed PowerPC-based. So, an x86 boot image would get you nowhere; see if you can find a PowerPC boot image.

Comment: I just checked... I'm using the lubuntu 14.04.2 desktop power pc ISO

Comment: Pretty sure PPC machines can't boot from USB. You'd likely need to get the ISO onto a small bootable internal HD partition, or It might boot from CD.

Comment: How would I get it onto an internal partition? Or should I say, how would I mount the ISO to the partition?